# Where can I find the text of past DSM versions to visualize revision history?

Tags: data, history-of-psychology, dsm

I'm interested in building a data visualization to learn more about the history of the DSM. (I'm inspired by [this visualization](https://fathom.info/traces/) of the edit history of Darwin's "Origin of Species" by Ben Fry, as well as these [journal](http://apsychoserver.psych.arizona.edu/JJBAReprints/PSYC621/Blashfield_etal_2014_ARCP.pdf) [articles](http://apsychoserver.psych.arizona.edu/JJBAReprints/PSYC621/Blashfield_etal_2014_ARCP.pdf) about DSM history.) [image: screenshot of Ben Fry's visualization of Darwin's "Origin of Species"]

Not being a psychologist or med student myself, is it a non-starter to try and obtain past texts in electronic form (i.e. as data)? Does anyone have suggestions of where to start looking/asking?

Thanks.

Comment: The American Psychiatric Association (APA) is the publisher of all the DSMs and has an article on the history of the DSM at https://www.psychiatry.org/psychiatrists/practice/dsm/history-of-the-dsm but I am unaware of any ability to obtain text searchable electronic formats of DSMs prior to DSM5 legally. Have you tried contacting the APA?